# ISource format for XPath 2.0 formatting date /time functions?

Tags: xpath

Der experts,

question about the following XPath 2.0 functions:
format-date() for a date
format-time()

If I want to format arbitrary input date time formats is there a possibility to define an input pattern t that should be converted to a target pattern.
Just wondering because I want to use different source formats in various places in my XSLT.

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

There is no parsing supported other than for the standardized YYYY-MM-DD and hh:mm:ss. In XPath 3.1 you additionally have  https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-ietf-date to parse an IETF date e.g. `parse-ietf-date("Thu, 18 May 2023 14:14:01 GMT")`.

Many date formats can be easily transformed in the the required one by using `replace`.

Depending on your XPath/XSLT processor you can of course also often call into the underlying programming platform (e.g. .NET or Java) to exploit the broader and internationalized date/time parsing support of that platform.

Comment: Thank you for this commenmt. Interesting to see this new parsing function. What exactly would be returned by this function and how can additional formatting logic beapplied to the parsed format?

Comment: Well, the link to the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-ietf-date I posted has the function signature as `fn:parse-ietf-date($value as xs:string?) as xs:dateTime?` so the function returns an `xs:dateTime` value obviously as that is how date/times are represented in the type system of XPath/XSLT 2.0 and later and XQuery 1 and later. As for formatting any `xs:dateTime` for output, you use https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-dateTime `format-dateTime`.